# Ruby on rails - pass variable to "new" action from previous view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have view Event#show. At this view user may choose how many people will join the event and choose the term. Then he may click "Purchase" which will redirect him to Transaction#new. Here I'd like to pre-fill these two values.

What is best way to do that? Where should I store these variables?

I'm thinking about:

```
<%= link_to new_transaction_path({ ..... })
```

...but I have no idea how to pass values to link_to parameters. Here's how i let user choose count of people:

```
<%= f.select(:seleced_seats, @event.seats, {}, { :class => 'form-control' }) %>
```

Comment: Should I store the data in session? At this time the object isn't created.

Comment: Any reason why not redirect  to `new_transaction_path` directly in EventsController?

Comment: No reason. But I don't see any benefits/solution in it.

Answer (score 1):

> I have view Event#show. At this view user may choose how many people
>   will join the event and choose the term. Then he may click "Purchase"
>   which will redirect him to Transaction#new.

So you can make a form from from where user can choose how many people can join and terms:

```
<%= form_tag("/transaction", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:people, "How Many People:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:people) %>
  <%= options_for_select([['terms 1', 1], ['terms 2', 2], ...]) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Purchase") %>
<% end %>
```

So you are getting a get or post request like `/transaction?people=3`
Now from `params[:people]` you can access information of your next form like the following:

```
<%= form_tag("/transaction", method: "post") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:people, "How Many People:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag :people, params[:people], disabled: true %>
  ...

  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```